# turn on language error and spell check in LyX

Tags: lyx, spelling

I would like to have highlighted the words that are not recognized by the system for the given language (English).

For the moment I am using LyX on Windows 10.

Comment: Do you mean continuous spellcheck? Click on "Abc" with the wavy underline, or go to Tools > Preferences > Language Settings > Spellchecker and check the box for "Spellcheck continuously".

Comment: Tool > Preferences > Language settings > Spellchecker > Spellchecker engine (that should be already installed).

Comment: @scottkosty, I think this is deserving of an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Click on "Abc" with the wavy underline, or go to Tools > Preferences > Language Settings > Spellchecker and check the box for "Spellcheck continuously".