# LyX: How to create shortcut to toggle on or off "Spellcheck continuously"?

Tags: lyx, shortcut

To toggle on and off "Spellcheck continuously", I [can](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354591/turn-on-language-error-and-spell-check-in-lyx)

> Click on "Abc" with the wavy underline, or go to Tools > Preferences > Language Settings > Spellchecker and check the box for "Spellcheck continuously".

How do I create a keyboard shortcut for this action (i.e. toggle on or off "Spellcheck continuously")?

(I tried following the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut) but it turns out that when I toggle on or off "Spellcheck continuously", there's an insanely long set of messages/commands in the Messages Pane and I'm not sure how to translate that to a shortcut.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Tools</kbd>
→ <kbd>Preferences ...</kbd> 
→ <kbd>Editing</kbd>
→ <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd>
→ <kbd>Cursor, Mouse and **Editing Functions**</kbd>
→  <kbd>**spelling-continously**</kbd>
→ <kbd>Modify</kbd>
→  <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + H</kbd> (or whatever unused shortcut that you want)
→ <kbd>OK</kbd>
→ <kbd>OK</kbd>